# Excel GETPIVOTDATA - I don't want to reference all fields in pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that breaks my orders into "is_tv", "website_COuntry", "year_order" and "week_order"

=GETPIVOTDATA("orders",pivot_cats_byweek!$A$3,"is_tv",1,"website_country","CA","year_order",2013,"week_order",46)

I would like to create a table where I can summarise just on the year. I would have thought I could just do something like this from the pivot table where I just remove the week references but I get a #REF error.

=GETPIVOTDATA("orders",pivot_cats_byweek!$A$3,"is_tv",1,"website_country","CA","year_order",2013)

Is there a way of doing this without creating another pivot table?

Thanks.

Comment: I never figured this out. I assume it's a silly excel thing?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your post, here are two ideas:

1. Group by "Year' in your pivot table and add subtotals
2. If you can't group by Year, there's always the "Helper Column" idea...

   - Create a field in your data table that looks at date of a transaction and returns the Year
   - Group by "Year" in your pivot table